# PostgreSQL Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. column "state" is of type status but expression is of type character varying

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to create a SQL statement using java. The problem is I am using

```
 stmt.setString(9, ev.getState().status());
```

for a variable I am trying to insert into a SQL column of type status

```
 CREATE TYPE STATUS AS ENUM ('APPROVED', 'CLOSED','STARTED', 'WAITING');
```

It is throwing me an exception of

```
column "state" is of type status but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Did I make a mistake or do I actually need to cast the value in sql? If yes, how does one cast in this situation?

Full Statement:

```
     PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Event (EventNum, EventName, startHour, endHour, startMin, endMin, startDate, endDate, State, depName) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?::date, ?::date, ?, ?)");




     stmt.setInt(1, ev.getEventNum());
     stmt.setString(2, ev.getName());
     stmt.setInt(3, ev.getStartHour());
     stmt.setInt(4, ev.getEndHour());
     stmt.setInt(5, ev.getStartMinute());
     stmt.setInt(6, ev.getEndMinute());
     stmt.setString(7, ev.getStartYear() + "-" + ev.getStartMonth() + "-" + ev.getStartDate());
     stmt.setString(8, ev.getEndYear() + "-" + ev.getEndMonth() + "-" + ev.getEndDate());
     stmt.setString(9, ev.getState().status());
     stmt.setString(10, ev.getDepartment());



     stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are using Prepared Statements - PostgreSQL gets info from client side, so parameter is `varchar` because you are using `setString` method. You should inform Postgres with explicit cast, so that input datatype is different.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO Event (EventNum, EventName, startHour, endHour, startMin, endMin, startDate, endDate, State, depName)
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?::date, ?::date, ?::status, ?)");
```

All data is passed in text form (it is default) - so that is not a problem with passed values. PostgreSQL uses strict type system - and without explicit casting doesn't allow cast from `varchar` to `date`, `enum`, `int`, ...

Comment: Just wanted to add that this also works if one is using named parameters too in Spring JDBC e.g. `:paramName::xml`

Comment: worked for me:

INSERT INTO Student (id,name,age,creationTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?::date)

Comment: @Pavel
while doing select also should we use in this way like below?
select * from Event where State=?::status

Answer (score 1):

you must will be have same problem if you use DBeaver.

try:

1.right click on your postgres db

2.edit connection/general/database

3.change database to the base in the context of which you want to make changes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store a String in a Enum type field. You need to use the setObject method and also provide the type like this

```
stmt.setObject(9, ev.getState().status(), Types.OTHER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Pavel Stehule,

If we want to add the date with time, we should use the following expression.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO Event (EventNum, EventName, startHour, endHour, startMin, endMin, startDate, endDate, State, depName)
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?::timestamp, ?, ?, ?)");
```