# Table not found in integration tests when using TestContainers with Flyway

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, flyway, testcontainers

I am trying to connect to Postgres database instance of [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) but I get the error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "proposal" does not exist` in Spring data repository class "ProposalRepository" when running the "HelloRestControllerTest"

The flyway is enabled in the config.

I created a demo project with just the basic stuff.

HelloRestController:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Proposal
import com.example.demo.repo.ProposalRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.data.repository.findByIdOrNull
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class HelloRestController @Autowired constructor(val proposalRepository: ProposalRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun hello(): ResponseEntity<Proposal>{
        val result = proposalRepository.findByIdOrNull("123") //error is thrown here.
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result)
    }
}
```

ProposalRepository:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Proposal
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface ProposalRepository : CrudRepository<Proposal, String>
```

Entity:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
@Table(name = "proposal")
data class Proposal(

  @Id
  @Column(name = "proposal_id")
  val proposalId: String,

  @Column(name = "amount", nullable = true)
  val amount: BigDecimal?,

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  val userId: String? = null
)
```

Flyway SQL script:

```
create table proposal (
      proposal_id                           varchar(50),
      amount                                decimal not null ,
      user_id                               varchar(35)
);
```

application-it-test.yml in src/test/resources folder:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    #driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.6:///databasename
    hikari:
      max-lifetime: 500000
      connection-timeout: 300000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      minimum-idle: 1
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}
    locations: 'classpath:db/migration/postgresql'
    table: FLY_VERSION
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.21</kotlin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.3</testcontainers.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- excluded because REST assured 4.3.0+ expects Groovy 3+ (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1283) -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- excluded because REST assured 4.3.0+ expects Groovy 3+ (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1283) -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- excluded because REST assured 4.3.0+ expects Groovy 3+ (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1283) -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

HelloRestControllerTest:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured.given
import io.restassured.http.ContentType
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("it-test")
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 1234)
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@Testcontainers
class HelloRestControllerTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    final val portNumber = 0

    val baseUrl = "http://localhost:$portNumber"


    companion object {
        @Container
        var postgreSQL: PostgreSQLContainer<*> = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.6")

        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun postgreSQLProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.datasource.username") { postgreSQL.username }
            registry.add("spring.datasource.password") { postgreSQL.password }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val helloResponse = given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .get("$baseUrl$portNumber/hello")
            .andReturn()
        println(helloResponse.body)
    }
}
```

The code and configuration looks fine so I am not able to figure out what is the problem. What could be the issue here?

**EDIT:**

If I add `@Sql` annotation in `HelloRestControllerTest` as shown below, I do not see any error. It looks like Flyway is not able to run the scripts to the right database or something. Not sure why?

`@Sql(scripts = ["classpath:/db/migration/postgresql/V01__PROPOSAL.sql"])`

Comment: One suspicion here, because it struck me in the past several times:
I cannot find the database name in any of your code / configuration. e.g. in `postgreSQLProperties` or `datasource` configuration.

Comment: The `testcontainers` use the jdbc url `jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.6:///databasename`. https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#using-postgresql. Not sure if I need to mention some custom database name. The hostname, port and database name will be ignored by testcontainer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912066/spring-boot-test-using-testcontainers-postgresql

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test, docker system prune -af

Comment: Looks like Flyway is having some issue because `@Sql` annotation is working fine with `Testcontainers` postgres database. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873514/postgresql-hint-you-will-need-to-rewrite-or-cast-the-expression-column-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the application-it-test.yml as shown below:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    #driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.6:///databasename?stringtype=unspecified
    hikari:
      max-lifetime: 500000
      connection-timeout: 300000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      minimum-idle: 1
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: 'classpath:db/migration/postgresql'
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

under flyway variable in yml file you only need to mention the `enable` and `locations` values. Everything else like url, schemas, table, etc should be **removed**. Otherwise Flyway does not work together with `TestContainers` in integration test.

The change needs to be done in both the test yml file and real application's yml file as well.

Comment: For Spring Boot (Before version 2.3.0) you need to specify the driver manually spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver